# Finding a probability density function from a moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Below is Problem 3.66  from the third edition of book "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" by Mendenahll, Scheaffer and Wackerly. This problem can be found on page 114.
Problem:
Find the distribution of the random variable $Y$ given that its moment-generating function is:
$$ m(t) = \left( \frac{1}{3}e^t + \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)  \right )^5 $$
Answer:
Let $f(y)$ be the density function we seek.
\begin{align*}
m(t) &= \int_0^{\infty} e^{ty}f(y) \, dy \\
\left( \frac{1}{3}e^t + \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)  \right )^5 &= \int_0^{\infty} e^{ty}f(y) \, dy \\
\end{align*}

At this point, I am stuck. I am tempted to differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ but I am not sure what you get when you do that.

Comment: What's the MGF of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut The moment generating function for the binomial distribution is $(pe^t + 1 - p)$. I am thinking I can now solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the MGF:

$$m(t)=\left(\frac13e^t+\frac23\right)^5=\sum_{k=0}^5 e^{kt}{5\choose k}\left(\frac13\right)^k\left(\frac23\right)^{5-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{kt}P(X=k)$$

Hence, for $0\le k\le 5$,

$$P(X=k)={5\choose k}\left(\frac13\right)^k\left(\frac23\right)^{5-k}$$

And for all other values of $k$, $P(X=k)=0$.

And you should recognize a binomial distribution.